# How to implement BitSet with Go?

Tags: go

I didn't find a BitSet package in Go, so I tried to implement it.
I'd like to use a array of uint64 to store the bits.

I need the number of bits to allocate the uint64 array.
With Java, I can define a constructor that takes an integer.
While Go doesn't provide constructor, how can I properly initialize 
the BitSet 'object' when user call new()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare bitSet as a private struct:

```
type bitSet struct {
  len int
  array []uint64
}
```

Expose the interface BitSet:

```
type BitSet interface {
  Has(pos int) bool
  Add(pos int) bool
  Len() int
}
```

Also expose a function NewBitSet:

```
func NewBitSet(len int) BitSet {
  return &bitSet{len, make(uint64, (len+7) / 8) }
}
```

This is a Go way for encapsulation: share an interface, not the implementation.

Comment: I don't fully agree with this solution. I think a bitset is too specific to be an interface. It allows you to have different bitsets that implement the same interface, but do you really need such a thing? It seems to me that you can probably come up with a bitset implementation that will work well for pretty much any use and just always use that. Multiple implementations will likely just confuse people.

Comment: There are a lot of cases when you need another implementation: large spare bitSet, distributed/transactional bitSet, virtual bitSet (setting/clearing a bit corresponds to some action) and so on.

Comment: I feel there are no uniform ways to initialize object in Go. :(
new(BitSet), BitSet.New(), NewBitSet(),... How are they related?

Comment: BitSet.New() and NewBitSet() are really the same thing with different names, since NewBitSet will necessarily be part of the BitSet package. It might be more correct to say BitSet.NewBitSet(), which seems redundant and is why Go prefers to simply say "New" when a package has the same name as an object type. I think it's safe to say that for packages, you'll usually be using some kind of constructor-like function. It's often the case that there are unexported members of a struct or (like in Ivan's example) there is a completely unexported type that implements an interface.

Comment: Thanks! Since now I provides BitSet.New() to properly initialize objects, is it possible to disable the new(BitSet) invocation?
And if I want to initialize a object by different parameters, I have to define several functions with different names like NewA(), NewB(), NewC()?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to disable new(BitSet), aside from doing what Ivan did in not exporting the type. Also, since Go unfortunately does not have overloaded functions or optional function arguments, you will have to create differently named functions for different parameter combinations. I'd recommend making as few such functions as possible.

Comment: Effective Go (http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#generality) explains this technique.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly a good technique in the right situation. I just don't believe this is one of those situations, and on that I'll simply agree to disagree.

Comment: "BitSet" has completely different meanings in different places. For example, Java's BitSet does not have a length.

Answer (score 16):

Go's standard [`big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) can be used as a bit set:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    var bits big.Int
    for i := 1000; i < 2000; i++ {
        bits.SetBit(&bits, i, 1)
    }
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        if bits.Bit(i) != 0 {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/xbIK-boouqC

Answer (score 3):

If you use a []uint64 slice to store your data, then the zero slice could function as the empty BitSet. In fact appending to a nil slice allocates a new array for you, although the Language Specification doesn't appear to guarantee that. With that kind of setup, new(BitSet) would be immediately usable. Example:

bitset.go:

```
package bitset

const size = 64

type bits uint64

// BitSet is a set of bits that can be set, cleared and queried.
type BitSet []bits

// Set ensures that the given bit is set in the BitSet.
func (s *BitSet) Set(i uint) {
    if len(*s) < int(i/size+1) {
        r := make([]bits, i/size+1)
        copy(r, *s)
        *s = r
    }
    (*s)[i/size] |= 1 << (i % size)
}

// Clear ensures that the given bit is cleared (not set) in the BitSet.
func (s *BitSet) Clear(i uint) {
    if len(*s) >= int(i/size+1) {
        (*s)[i/size] &^= 1 << (i % size)
    }
}

// IsSet returns true if the given bit is set, false if it is cleared.
func (s *BitSet) IsSet(i uint) bool {
    return (*s)[i/size]&(1<<(i%size)) != 0
}
```

bitset_test.go:

```
package bitset

import "fmt"

func ExampleBitSet() {
    s := new(BitSet)
    s.Set(13)
    s.Set(45)
    s.Clear(13)
    fmt.Printf("s.IsSet(13) = %t; s.IsSet(45) = %t; s.IsSet(30) = %t\n",
               s.IsSet(13), s.IsSet(45), s.IsSet(30))
    // Output: s.IsSet(13) = false; s.IsSet(45) = true; s.IsSet(30) = false
}
```

Comment: The language specification guarantees that `append` works for nil slices. It uses a nil slice [in an example for append](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices). (To make this conclusion valid I had to assume that the examples in the Go language specification are normative, other than in the C standard.)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you can't properly initialize the `BitSet` object when a client calls `new`().

The best thing you can do is make it so that your `BitSet`'s zero value is valid. This is what types like `list.List`, `sync.Mutex`, and `big.Int` do. This way you know that it's impossible for a client to get an invalid value.

The next best thing you can do is create a constuctor-like function (named `NewBitSet` in this case) and expect clients to call it.

Comment: Then I can call List.New() and not new(List)?
For a new package, how can I know how to create a new object?

Comment: I think that's right, although I might be remembering wrong. You wouldn't want to call new(List) even if it's allowed since you won't be able to properly initialize the object. You can figure out how to create a new object the same way you'd figure out how to do anything else within a package: read the documentation. Usually these constructor-like functions will have the word "New" in them, at least.

Comment: It turns out you can create an object with unexported fields via new(). It just doesn't seem very useful, unless that object has some kind of initialization function you can call on it.

Comment: Actually if you read the doc of the list package, you will see that "The zero value for List is an empty list ready to use." That means it's perfectly valid to evaluate new(List) and immediately start using the resulting list object.

Comment: @Matt You're right, and I've changed my answer accordingly. I like to imagine that maybe list didn't work this way when I answered this question originally. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented [my own](https://github.com/astef/bitmask) too, and that's how It works:

```
bm := bitmask.New(4)        // [4]{0000}
bm.Set(3)                   // [4]{0001}
bm.Slice(2, 4).ToggleAll()  // [4]{0010}
bm.Slice(1, 3).ToggleAll()  // [4]{0100}
bm.Slice(0, 2).ToggleAll()  // [4]{1000}
bm.Clear()                  // [4]{0000}
```

As others have answered, there's a convention to use `New` function to mimic the constructor.