# Using bitsets in golang to represent capabilities

Tags: go

I am new to Golang and would like to model physical devices for measuring quantities such as light intensity, mass, electric current and so forth. So as a starting point I will define a device struct as follows:

```
const (
    // Light can be measured in the form of luminosity
    Light             = 1<< iota
    Mass             
    ElectricalCurrent 
)

type PhysicalDevice struct{
   Owner       string
   ID          string
   Description string
}
```

I am a confused now on how to express the device's capabilities (what it can measure) and the units of measurement. For example I would like to express that a physical device can measure electrical currents in amperes. However, I also want to express that a PhysicalDevice can measure more than one quantity. For example it could measure electrical current and temperature.

The PhysicalDevice's capabilities are not known in advance and can contain an arbitrary combination of capabilities.

I was thinking of using something equivalent to a C++ bitset for expressing the physical quantities a device can measure (would this be the right approach in the first place?).

I did not find the Go bitset type and not sure how to express that. I also need to map the measured physical quantity to a corresponding unit.

Comment: This is too vague for us to be able to help you. Is the goal to minimize memory used for each instance, or is the goal just to have arbitrary combinations of capabilities? Are the capabilities known in advance or dynamic? If you insist on using something similar to bitset, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311373/how-to-implement-bitset-with-go

Comment: You should also understand that trying to replicate another language's features in Go is generally regarded as a bad idea.  There is a 'go' way of doing things.  You might want to consider `iota` and bitmask operations like [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/Dm3X-akr31).  This approach [is commonly used in the standard library](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#ImportMode).

Comment: Yes I agree. I am new to go so trying to figure things out. Hence the question :). I have added iota consts to the sample

Comment: @DanEsparza Actually you have pretty much given me the answer. So if you want to put your comment as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @BigONotation glad to hear it!  Done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should understand that trying to replicate another language's features in Go is generally regarded as a bad idea. There is a 'go' way of doing things.

You might want to consider `iota` and bitmask operations like [this example on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Dm3X-akr31).  I have included the code here as well (in all its plagiarized glory):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    TestAddFlag()
    TestHasFlag()
    TestClearFlag()
    TestToggleFlag()

    fmt.Println("all tests passed")
}

type Bitmask uint32

func (f Bitmask) HasFlag(flag Bitmask) bool { return f&flag != 0 }
func (f *Bitmask) AddFlag(flag Bitmask)     { *f |= flag }
func (f *Bitmask) ClearFlag(flag Bitmask)   { *f &= ^flag }
func (f *Bitmask) ToggleFlag(flag Bitmask)  { *f ^= flag }

const (
    TESTFLAG_ONE Bitmask = 1 << iota
    TESTFLAG_TWO
    TESTFLAG_THREE
)

func TestAddFlag() {

    var mainFlag Bitmask = TESTFLAG_TWO

    mainFlag.AddFlag(TESTFLAG_THREE)

    if mainFlag&(1<<TESTFLAG_THREE) != 0 {
        panic("failed")
    }

}

func TestClearFlag() {

    var mainFlag Bitmask = TESTFLAG_ONE | TESTFLAG_THREE

    mainFlag.ClearFlag(TESTFLAG_THREE)

    if mainFlag&(1<<TESTFLAG_ONE) != 0 {
        panic("failed")
    }

}

func TestHasFlag() {

    var mainFlag Bitmask = TESTFLAG_ONE | TESTFLAG_THREE

    if !mainFlag.HasFlag(TESTFLAG_THREE) {
        panic("failed")
    }

}

func TestToggleFlag() {
    flag := TESTFLAG_ONE | TESTFLAG_THREE

    flag.ToggleFlag(TESTFLAG_ONE)
    if flag.HasFlag(TESTFLAG_ONE) {
        panic("failed")
    }
    flag.ToggleFlag(TESTFLAG_ONE)
    if !flag.HasFlag(TESTFLAG_ONE) {
        panic("failed")
    }
}
```

This approach is [commonly used in the standard library](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#ImportMode).

Comment: I think there’s a little mistake in TestAddFlag() function: it should be: if mainFlag&TESTFLAG_THREE == 0 { ... Since TESTFLAG_THREE is already a bitmask.

Answer (score 5):

Define the capabilities using `= 1 << iota`:

```
const (
  Light Capability = 1 << iota
  Mass
  ElectricalCurrent
  Energy
)
```

Notice that the expression is only needed on the first constant. The same expression (but with an updated value of `iota`) will be used on the consecutive lines in the same group.

Here's a complete working example:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
)

type Capability int

const (
  // Light can be measured in the form of luminosity
  Light Capability = 1 << iota
  Mass
  ElectricalCurrent
  Energy
)

func (c Capability) String() string {
  var caps []string
  if c&Light > 0 {
    caps = append(caps, "Light")
  }
  if c&Mass > 0 {
    caps = append(caps, "Mass")
  }
  if c&ElectricalCurrent > 0 {
    caps = append(caps, "ElectricalCurrent")
  }
  if c&Energy > 0 {
    caps = append(caps, "Energy")
  }
  return strings.Join(caps, "|")
}

type PhysicalDevice struct {
  Owner       string
  ID          string
  Description string
  Capability  Capability
}

func (pd PhysicalDevice) String() string {
  return "Owner: " + pd.Owner + "\n" +
    "ID: " + pd.ID + "\n" +
    "Description: " + pd.Description + "\n" +
    "Capability: " + pd.Capability.String() + "\n"
}

func main() {
  dev := PhysicalDevice{
    Owner:       "Albert Einstein",
    ID:          "E=mc^2",
    Description: "My well-known formula as a device",
    Capability:  Energy | Mass | Light,
  }
  fmt.Println(dev)
}
```

The code can be found on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/p0D7OukxZ2j).